# Keepiing only 3 FY tables in the database at a time, rest all tables needs to Drop

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to keep only 3 financial year tables in my database rest I need to drop the table

Means I have a table something like

```
KT201705, KT201502 , KT201412 , KT201605 , KT201709 , KT201506
```

Current financial year is    2017-2018
Last Financial year          2016-2017
Last to Last financial year  2015-2016

I want to Keep tables like

```
KT201705,  
KT201605,    
KT201709,  
KT201506
```

I want to drop all the tables created in financial year before that which means tables like

```
KT201412,   
KT201502
```

What I tried:

```
select 'DROP TABLE ' + NAME from sys.tables
WHERE NAME LIKE 'KT2%'
```

But I cannot figured out the financial year part.

I also checked this query:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN DatePart(Month, convert(varchar(10),GETDATE(),112)) >= 4
        THEN DatePart(Year, convert(varchar(10),GETDATE(),112)) + 1
        ELSE DatePart(Year,convert(varchar(10),GETDATE(),112))
   END AS Fiscal_Year
```

But it is giving only the current financial year.

Can anyone have any idea how to proceed further??

Comment: Why are you storing this data in different tables and not one table with a column telling you which financial year the row belongs to?

Comment: Table is getting created dynamically every month.

Comment: That may be so, but *why?*  Why not just `insert` the data into the same table?

Answer (score 0):

Will this work

```
;WITH cteNum
AS(
    SELECT N = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
    FROM master.dbo.spt_values V
)
SELECT 'DROP TABLE ' + NAME 
FROM sys.tables 
CROSS APPLY cteNum N
WHERE NAME LIKE 'KT'+ CONVERT(NVARCHAR(4),DATEADD(YEAR, -N.N, GETDATE()), 102) + '%'
AND N.N >= 2 AND  N.N <=10
```

The same query slightly amended returns this list of dates

```
;WITH cteNum
AS(
    SELECT N = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
    FROM master.dbo.spt_values V
)
SELECT yyyyDate = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(4),DATEADD(YEAR, -N.N, GETDATE()), 102)
FROM cteNum N
WHERE N.N >= 2 AND  N.N <=10
```

[image]

Comment: Your 1st Query is giving me blank record

Comment: What does this query return?  `;WITH cteNum
AS(
    SELECT N = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
    FROM master.dbo.spt_values V
)
SELECT 'KT'+ CONVERT(NVARCHAR(4),DATEADD(YEAR, -N.N, GETDATE()), 102) + '%'
FROM cteNum N
WHERE N.N >= 2 AND  N.N <=10`

Comment: It returns KT2007% , KT2008% ans so on

Comment: Isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: No it is not what I wanted.

Comment: You said "But I cannot figured out the financial year part."??